# Change retention time for backup in Azure SQL Database

Tags: backup, azure, sql

is there any way to change retention time for backup in Azure SQL? For example, there is some backup with retention time for 1 month and I want to change retention time for that backup for 1 year, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the retention of the Azure SQL backups depending on the SKU you are using, but only up to 35 days. If you need longer than that then you need to look at long term retention for SQL backups which allows you to store backups in blob storage for up to 10 years, details here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sam. I have already changed retention time for PiTR backups. Can I change retention time for backups kept in Recovery Services Vault? For example, 15 days ago some backup was taken from SQL, retention time for it is 30 days, so it will be deleted after 15 days. What if I want to keep that backup for 1 year? Is it possible to change retention time for that specific backup?